# Trim Jmeter variable value

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I need to Parameterize Mobile Number, which i am doing from CSV and in My next request i need to pass first 4 digit of my mobile number, so is it possible to trim variable value in jmeter so that i can pick value from csv and store that value in variable(pass in Mobile Number Field) and in next request i can trim the same variable (pick first 4 digit) and pass into next request?

[Please find the attached snapshot for the request where i need to pass only first 4 digit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Fbq.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using u.e. [__javaScript()](http://$%7B__javaScript(%22$%7BMobileNumber%7D%22.substring(0%5C,4),foo)%7D) function as follows:

1. If you use [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) there is a [__substring()](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#substringsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-0-4-2-font-sup) function
2. Trim variable on-the-fly:

   ```
   ${__javaScript("${MobileNumber}".substring(0\,4),)}
   ```
3. Trim variable and store the value into `${foo}` variable:

   ```
   ${__javaScript("${MobileNumber}".substring(0\,4),foo)}
   ```

Mind the following:

- surround variable with quotation marks so JavaScript engine could consider it a string
- escape commas in functions with backslash
- if you want to store result into a variable - make it a last function parameter

References:

- [JavaScript String substring() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)
- [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series

Comment: Thanks Its Working :)